# Arrays and Copying Arrays

Tags: arrays, netbeans, reverse

The project I am doing has to be able to display both the first and second arrays. Meaning that I need the second array to copy the first array. Other than just copying the arrays I have to reverse it into a third array all into one loop. How do I make it so the first Array doesn't lose its value once it is made equal to the second Array and put through a loop?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
            // Constants Section
                final int FIVE = 5;                          
                final int ONE = 1;                          

                // Variable Declaration Section
                int[] firstArray = {1,2,3,4,5};             
                int[] secondArray;                                                          
                int[] finalArray;                                                       
                int i;                                       


    // Variable Initialization Section
                secondArray = new int[FIVE];                
                finalArray = new int[FIVE];                 

    // Code Section
                  for (i = 0; i <FIVE; i++)       
                {  
                    secondArray = firstArray;  
                    finalArray = firstArray;
                }

                for (i = FIVE - 1; i >= 0; i--)   
                {

                    System.out.println("Array1 = " + firstArray[i] + " Array2= " +   secondArray[i] + " Array3= " + finalArray [i]);
                }




    }
 }
```

I AM COMPLETELY CLUELESS ABOUT CODING. I AM A HIGHSCHOOL STUDENT WHO WAS PUT INTO AN IMPOSSIBLE CLASS. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Post an example of desired output. Also post your so far tried code.

Comment: `array_merge` + `array_reverse` ?

Comment: Can you add the language you are using as a tag

Comment: @Rikesh I have posted what I have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

The code above seems more to me a language other than php.

**Pseudo code for copying can be like this**

```
for (i=0;i<firstArray.length();i++){

     secondArray[i]=firstArray[i];
}
```

**Pseudo code for reversing(say firstArray) it**

```
for (i=0,j=firstArray-1;j>i;j--,i++){
     temp=firstArray[i];
     firstArray[i]=firstArray[j];
     firstArray[j]=temp;   
}
```